# C# Xpath Tables

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, html-table

I have the xml code that contains to a table with 2 rows.

```
<table>
       <thead>
              <tr>
                  <td class="num">test</td>
                  <td class="num">test2</td>
              </tr>
       </thead>
</table>
```

I am using xpath to grap the data from the row.
how do i retrieve only the first row data from the table and not all the data.

The xpath code i am using now is:

```
/table/thead/tr/th[@class='num']
```

And my current output is:

```
test
test2
```

What do I have to add in the xpath code so I can select the first row only?

Comment: so what do you want it to be?

Comment: What output is it you're expecting?

Comment: That xpath shouldn't be returning any results because it doesnt map to anything

Comment: I'm sorry , I really don't know why you can use the /th[@class='num']
to get the two valus but your xml is <td class="num">test</td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is the expected output, the XPath expression asks for *all* nodes which match, and the two you get are therefore correct.

If you want only the first one, you can do this:

```
/table/thead/tr/th[@class='num'][1]
```

Otherwise post your expectation...

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what i needed, i saw that my question was totally wrong formulated, i have edited it now! I know its a little late but thanks!! and you know what they say... better late than never :)

Comment: @LarsWerkman, thanks for the late feedback - still appreciated!